# jQuery toggle and jQuery Mobile toggle, both trigger?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile, mobile

I just recently started working with jQuery Mobile. I ran into a issue that I don't get quite yet.

I got this code. What it does is that it triggers the `toggle` twice. One for jQuery and the other for jQuery Mobile (works as expected when removing reference to jQM). Any ideas on how to avoid this for use with Mobile? Adding namespace...?

```
var navigation = $main_nav.find("[data-toggle-id='" + target + "']");
navigation.toggle(200, function() {
      console.log('toogle');
});
```

**EDIT**
Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/4mpdR/4/

I don't get the same behaviour here but this is basically my setup.

**Edit2**

```
$(function () {
    $(document).on('click', '.nav__toggle', function () {
        var $main_nav = $('.main-nav');
        var target = $(this).data('target');

        var navigation = $main_nav.find("[data-toggle-id='" + target + "']");
        navigation.toggle(200, function() {
            console.log('toogle');
        });
    });
});
```

**Edit3**
It's just a `<nav>`. looking in the console I see that it triggers twice and one time it has the reference to my actual .js file, second is the VM[number], removing jQuery Mobile eliminates the VM.

```
[nav.main-nav__collapse.clearfix, prevObject: jQuery.fn.jQuery.init[1], context: document, selector: ".main-nav [data-toggle-id='main-nav__collapse']", constructor: function, init: function…]
0: nav.main-nav__collapse.clearfix
context: document
length: 1
prevObject: jQuery.fn.jQuery.init[1]
selector: ".main-nav [data-toggle-id='main-nav__collapse']"
__proto__: Object[0]
```

Comment: I think a JSfiddle would give a better insight... Can you add it?

Comment: And maybe you should go with `$(navigation).toggle()`...

Comment: If you are not getting same problem in fiddle, then you might have assigned event twice. If you can give your entire function, then we can look at it...

Comment: @j809 'navigation' is a jQuery object already.

Comment: Does `navigation` have multiple objects? Or is its content an array? Do a `console.log` for navigation and tell your output please...

Answer (score 0):

First you find out user agent(iphone,android,blackberry,webos) then you can separate the event of different platform

```
  $.browser.device = (/android|webos|iphone|ipad|ipod|blackberry|iemobile|opera mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase()));
```

now $.browser will return "device" for all above devices

Comment: thanks for answer but I can't see how that will help me in this situation?